# How does laravel resolve dependencies based on typehinting?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I know how an Inversion of Control container works and I know how to create one myself. But I only know how to do this by utilizing register and resolve methods.

I have looked in the Laravel documentation but I am stuck on trying to figure out how Laravel can resolve a dependency based on typehinting. Where is the missing link for this exact part?

When I am using a more traditional IoC container where I manually resolve stuff, I at least have to call a static method to get going. Laravel does not seem to need any of this.

Can somebody steer me in the right direction or set up a tiny example?

I have worked my way through:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dependency-injection-huh--net-26903

As a recap. Maybe somebody could set up a quick example with automatic resolution for typehinting or is this really complex?

Comment: Per your question, it looks like you want to know how Laravel resolves DI through type hint. What you're looking for is called Reflection in PHP. With reflection, you create a mirror object of a class inside a variable and you can navigate through it before making an instance.

Comment: How does the reflectionclass fire whenever a typehint is used though?

Comment: it's doesn't. If you pay close attention to laravel, you only have DI for classes / methods that Laravel invokes for you. If you instance an object manually you'll see that DI does not save you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic happens in Laravel's [Container.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L612) class where dependencies are automatically resolved using reflection.

Only classes that are instantiated or "made" using Laravel's DI container will benefit from its dependency injection functionality.

Comment: I'm guessing all controllers are simply being instantiated based on the router that receives a url and controller name. Where does this part happen though? The actually "new up" statement for a controller instance. Also at what point does a controller link with the container so that it might use the reflection from the container?

Comment: This all happens in the `build()` method. All classes that are built by Laravel's DI container are constructed inside this method. There are 2 return points within this method. The first is at [line 761](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L761) where the instantiated object is created using the `new` keyword if the class does not have a `__construct()` method defined. The second return point is [line 779](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L779) where the class is instantiated with arguments.